Testing a battery with a multimeter in diode mode
I did the test. I tested a couple of AA batteries (1.2V-1.5V) and CR2032 (2.5V-3.0V) with different amounts of usages, and one overly depleted AG44 battery (0.1V) and one rechargeable 18650 battery.
With the positive probe on the positive terminal and the negative probe on the negative terminal (case A), the multimeter always shows slightly lower readings than in DCV mode, most likely because of the internal resistance of the batteries. So in this case, the diode mode seems to correctly show the voltage drops.
However, with the positive probe on the negative terminal and the negative probe on the positive terminal (case B), it always shows approximately -280mV, with the only exception of the overly depleted battery.
The overly depleted battery shows approximately +500mV in the first case, and in the second case the reading gradually goes up from +400mV to +800mV over time.
Why is this? Why is it not showing the negative value of the same magnitude when the polarity is reversed? Does the multimeter adjust something in it to prevent internal damage, which leads to the incorrect readings? Or is there actually a mechanism to force batteries to output different voltages?

The reading is indeed expected to be multimeter model-specific, but it is in the end a function of the voltage the multimeter applies. Since the voltage drop is proportional to the resistance, as long as the multimeter's resistance remains constant during a diode test, we can calculate the voltage the multimeter applies.
For one of the AA batteries I have, I measured 1.493V in DCV, 1.337V in case A, and -283mV in case B. Therefore the voltage from the multimeter is less than 1.493V, or the voltage drop would've been higher than 1.493V in case A due to the internal resistance of the battery. A simple calculation shows the multimeter is applying ~1.152V (156mV:1.21V ≈ 1.493V-1.152V:1.493V+1.152V). Thus if you conservatively estimate the internal resistance of the battery to be 1Ω, the multimeter's resistance is only ~1.19Ω. This means 380mA would flow if you were to test a silicon diode with the same multimeter, assuming a silicon diode drops 700mV. I doubt that a diode tester would allow such a high current flow.
Three other batteries resulted in the following measurements:

(AA) 1.230V in DCV, 1.120V in case A, -286mV in case B
(AAA) 1.408V in DCV, 1.246V in case A, -285mV in case B
(The above two in series: -269 mV in case B)
(CR2032) 2.25V in DCV, 2+V in case A, -285mV in case B

If the readings are correct, the only sensible explanation seems to be that the multimeter is applying voltage adaptively.
In summary, assuming the readings are correct, there are two problems.

Is adaptive voltage in diode mode really a thing? It just seems enough to use a high resistance if you wanted to prevent damage. Maybe for better accuracy?

The current the multimeter allows to flow seems too high. I thought multimeters would use a very high resistance, which is why I thought there wouldn't be a big difference between case A and case B except for the sign.


(The overly depleted battery simply seems malfunctioning; the readings are unstable in both directions.)

I know it should be something about the circuitry which is unknown, and I am not interested in what it actually is, but whether it's possible, so one hypothetical scenario that would result in the readings I got is enough.

The “flipping the polarity” difference could be the result of the diode test trying to source current, but flipping the polarity forces it to try and sink it which it cannot do.  Probably no way to find out for sure without experiments on that specific meter and/or tearing it down to look inside.

The result of measuring batteries in diode mode depend on how your multimeter measures it. We can't know which multimeter you have, how it measures things in diode mode, and what kind of results it gives you when you misuse the diode mode to measure external voltage sources. The battery likely behaves differently depending on polarity in which way the multimeter tries to apply current through the battery.

@Justme Case B is the problem, but in case B, the power sources are simply connected in series. A battery acting weird when connected in series is not ordinary, is it?

@JaeseopAhn You are already trying unordinary things. Unless you do not know how your specific multimeter applies the voltage/current bias and how it measures the resulting voltage/current to show you a number, you are already doing undefined things. Also the voltage of any battery, especally a dead battery, will change if you try to push current through it in any direction. They are not ideal zero-ohm or even one-ohm voltage supplies, they are just metal electrodes floating in a chemical solution where current is generated by chemical reactions and there might not be chemicals left to react.

@JaeseopAhn You already have two answers that tell you that using the diode mode to test battery voltage is not sensible. If you disagree with those answers, I would suggest you would be better served by engaging those answers, rather than making extensive edits to your question. Those answers are correct, and nothing you add to your question will, imho, result in your test giving useful results.

Follow the instructions for the use of the meter.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Being insensible is one thing, and what happens in the insensible scenario is another thing. If the question was "Why can't a gasoline car run on diesel?" then you should explain what happens in the gasoline car with diesel, instead of just saying "because it's not designed like that." This answer is indeed correct, but it's probably not what the question wants to ask. Justme is addressing what might be happening inside, which is the kind of answer I wanted. The two answers are totally different to me.

You cannot measure external voltages like batteries in diode mode.
In diode mode, the two terminals are assumed to be connected to an unpowered semiconductor like a diode, and the most common case, the meter provides some small bias current and has some circuitry to measure the result to present you some result as voltage, but it might not be as simple as measuring the voltage at the probe terminals but maybe indirectly based on current flowing through internal bias circuit.
So the it may be a completely different circuitry with protection from external voltages being applied and with some limited measurement range.
It will not be expected that you can measure battery voltages for any sensible results in diode mode, because it is not intended to be used for that scenario.
In fact many multimeter manuals warn that diode mode should not be used for testing circuits that are powered as it may damage the meter.
For example a multimeter such as Uni-T UT60 supplies about 1.5mA constant current bias into the circuit and tries to measure the voltage. Supported open circuit voltage range is up to about 3.3V with 1mV resolution. Different meters use different bias currents, have different voltage ranges and resolutions.
So this is why it is impossible to have meaningful results by measuring batteries in diode mode.
Your meter seems to have protection circuitry that limits the internal voltage to about -280mV in the reverse direction to prevent damage.
And connected to a small button cell, the multimeter will force current into the button cell and try to charge it, which is why the voltage is higher than simply measuring the button cell idle voltage without charging current flowing into it. Which by the way do not like being charged and may damage.

I want to make it clear that this is purely out of theoretical curiosity. So I now understand that there might be a protection feature that limits the voltage in the reverse direction. But I still have one question left: in one of my experiments, 1.230V in DCV became 1.120V in diode mode. With a current of 1.5mA, if the voltage difference of 110mV was solely due to its internal resistance, it should be 73Ω, which is very unlikely. So it must be something else, if it's not simply a measurement/calculation error. What could possibly account for the voltage difference?

@JaeseopAhn The difference is explained by circuitry inside your or any other multimeter and that circuitry is unknown. Constant current sources are not ideal, and you cannot model a battery with a simple constant voltage supply with series resistance. You should experiment if your battery voltage really changes by 110mV if you try to charge it with 1.5mA current, or whatever your specific multimeter outputs with some compliance voltage. Primary batteries are not intended to be charged with even 1.5mA of current so their chemical reactiond may very well behave like that.

Oh right, if it was +1.5mA, the internal resistance of the battery would rather increase the voltage drop, so the voltage itself must have changed for whatever reason. I updated the question, and I will do the experiment you suggested soon, and if your hypothesis is correct I will accept your answer.

@JaeseopAhn  In order to eliminate the battery chemistries muddying your experiments/results, wouldn’t it be better to run a fixed DC voltage through an opamp follower plus series resistor? That way you can both source and sink current from the meter and to the opamp while not charging & discharging anything (i.e. measure a much more ideal voltage source instead of a battery). Then once you’ve reverse engineered the internal circuit of the meter, then you can apply it to batteries. Trying to tackle both things at the same time seems unscientific and could produce erroneous results.

@SteKulov You're totally right. I think that is probably the way to go. I will try that, thanks!

Well I was thinking that I would just accept your answer now because you're probably correct about the 110mV difference. Also it would kinda take some time for me to get things delivered to my address anyway, and if I have another question I will maybe ask it in a separate post.

The diode function of a DVM applies a low current to the diode and measures the resulting voltage, similar to making a resistance measurement.
Doing a diode test or resistance test on a voltage source or live circuit will give meaningless results.

I am aware that it applies a low current, and I also know a resistance test would result in a negative resistance if the voltage is not too low. I am not talking about how meaningful they are. The readings must be results of measurement not random numbers, however meaningless they might be.

You are using the meter in a manner not intended by the manufacturer, so the meter can do anything it wishes, and different meters may do different things.

If you mean different meters may apply different voltage in diode mode, by saying the meter can do anything, then you're correct, but that is not my question. I included more details above, so please take a look.
